# Simplest way to create a single page (with anonymous Access) to search a Sharepoint list Item and then Add/Edit/Delete in Sharepoint Online O365

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365

I have SharePoint O365 subscription in which there is a private site collection. In that site collection there is a site with a list named `xxx` with `columns (a,b,c)`

I want to enable any user ,with anonymous access to a page (like in the public site of O365), to search with a column "c" and be able to update all the `columns (a,b & c)` and save that record.

What is the best way to achieve this?